# Accepted behaviour while working in international collaborations

Tags: etiquette, interpersonal-issues, international, lab-meeting

How is getting-job-done outlook perceived in different parts of the academic world? In some parts of physics, I know a person who goes forward and suggests times and dates for meeting up for the workgroup and some improvements will be very welcome do to so since it is viewed as a responsible and active act. However, I noticed that in some research areas (which even might be the nature of the subject or the people involved) this might be seen as an imposing behaviour where they believe in suggesting a meeting and not stating any times/dates to give space to the other people involved.
My question is there any international standard or accepted etiquette in this regard?

Comment: While certainly there are some cultural tendencies, I expect that the perception of work attitudes depends primarily on the individuals involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no international standard of etiquette. Cultures differ so much between countries (and within countries) that I think it would be impossible to agree on the details of such a thing. What you are discovering is part of the fun of collaborating with other people from different countries: you get to indirectly learn about the cultures and working practices of those countries.

In situations like this, my advice is to take it on a case-by-case basis. Ask your collaborators early on whether they prefer you to take the lead on suggesting meeting times and related goals, or whether they would prefer to communicate with you as and when they make progress. That way you can ensure that everyone is happy as the collaboration goes on, and you can always check in with them later on to see that the arrangement is still working for everyone.